# getAttribute() returns null in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have buttons in HTML and I want to put sort of condition on them that whichever button is clicked i.e (if id of button is equal to 1) then it displays the CSV I have specified otherwise display a different CSV. I actually have 50 CSVS which I want to display but the getAttribute is returning null can anyone explain why? I'm a beginner at Javascript so haven't been able to find any solution yet.

Some snaps of the code:

cotton.html

[image]

report which gets displayed through reports.html i.e submission2.csv

[image]

```js
var link = document.querySelector('button');
console.log(link);
var target = link.getAttribute("id");
console.log(target);
pos = 1;

function catchit(no) {
  if (no == 1) {
    path = "/static/data/submission1.csv"
    console.log(path);
  } else if (no == 2) {
    path = "/static/data/submission2.csv"
    console.log(path);
  } else {
    path = "/static/data/submission2.csv"

  }

}


function parseData(createGraph) {
  if (target == 1) {
    catchit(1)
  } else {
    catchit(2)
  }

  Papa.parse(path, {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
      createGraph(results.data);

    }
  });
}


function createGraph(data) {
  var years = ['x'];
  var CottonYarn1 = ["Cotton Yuan/MT"];

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i][0] === undefined) {
      years.push(null);
    } else {
      years.push(data[i][0]);
    }
    if (data[i][1] === undefined) {
      CottonYarn1.push(null);
    } else {
      CottonYarn1.push(data[i][1]);
    }
    console.log(years);
    console.log(CottonYarn1);

  }
  parseData(createGraph);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.2/papaparse.min.js" ></script>

<div class="btn-group">

  <a  href={% url 'reports' %}> <button class="block"  id="1"onclick="catchit(this)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button></a>    
  <a  href={% url 'reports' %}> <button class="block"  id="2" onclick="catchit(this)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button></a>
  <a  href={% url 'reports' %}> <button class="block"  id="3" onclick="catchit(this)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button></a>

</div>
```

reports.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
  {% load static %}

   {% block main-content %}

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'stylesheets/style.css'%}">


  <div class="main ">
     <!doctype html>
       <html lang="en">
        <body>
     {% load static %}
      <link rel='stylesheet' 
       href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.css" 
        />

  <!-- Load c3.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'stylesheets/c3.css' %}" 
  type="text/css">
  
  <script src="{% static 'javascripts/allpredicted.js' %}"</script>
  </body>
  </div>
  </html>
```

Comment: What exactly does the console log shows? When you click the button element that shows in the console and it opens up the element, is that the button you expected and it indeed has `id` attribute?

Comment: It just gives null

Comment: Please click [edit], then click `[<>]` snippet editor and create a ***[mcve]*** with only RENDERED HTML, Script and CSS

Comment: You code works just fine for me, but notice that 2 of your id's are the same. Also why did you tag jquery for this

Comment: you have multiple `console.log()` throughout the code, they all return null?

Comment: You should not wrap links in buttons. Just style the links as buttons or the buttons as links

Comment: Also please delegate the click and have data-attributes on the buttons. to identify the report

Comment: @vanowm console.log(link) returns button.navbar-toggler and console.log(target) returns null. I think the correct button is not being selected?

Comment: Exactly, so narrow your querySelector down to let's say something like `.btn-group > button`

Comment: @mplugjan I've made those changes in the original code i'll edit them here

Comment: You have numeric IDs and you have two ID="2"

Comment: @TH are you sure the javascript is running after your html is rendered

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I placed it inside the div btn-group but I think querySelector is not selecting the button from cotton.html but somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

you have typo in your code, it should be like this:

```js
function catchit(id){
console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<button class="block"  id="1"onclick="catchit(this.id)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button></a>    
<button class="block"  id="2" onclick="catchit(this.id)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button>
 <button class="block"  id="3" onclick="catchit(this.id)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button>
```

Comment: how do I get this id outside the catchit function? I need to check a condition in the parseData function

Answer (score -1):

Seems like ID cannot be an attribute. You can rename your attribute by any other name but id.
try make it id1 or button-id and try.

```
var link = document.querySelector('button');
console.log(link);
var target = link.getAttribute("id1");
console.log(target);
pos = 1;

function catchit(no) {
  if (no == 1) {
    path = "/static/data/submission1.csv"
    console.log(path);
  } else if (no == 2) {
    path = "/static/data/submission2.csv"
    console.log(path);
  } else {
    path = "/static/data/submission2.csv"
console.log(path);
  }

}


function parseData(createGraph) {
  if (target == 1) {
    catchit(1)
  } else {
    catchit(2)
  }

  Papa.parse(path, {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
      createGraph(results.data);

    }
  });
}


function createGraph(data) {
  var years = ['x'];
  var CottonYarn1 = ["Cotton Yuan/MT"];

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i][0] === undefined) {
      years.push(null);
    } else {
      years.push(data[i][0]);
    }
    if (data[i][1] === undefined) {
      CottonYarn1.push(null);
    } else {
      CottonYarn1.push(data[i][1]);
    }
    console.log(years);
    console.log(CottonYarn1);

  }
  parseData(createGraph);
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.2/papaparse.min.js" ></script>

<div class="btn-group">

  <a  href={% url 'reports' %}> <button class="block"  id1="1"onclick="catchit(this)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button></a>    
  <a  href={% url 'reports' %}> <button class="block"  id1="2" onclick="catchit(this)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button></a>
  <a  href={% url 'reports' %}> <button class="block"  id1="3" onclick="catchit(this)" >Formget Online Form Builder Create Online Forms</button></a>

</div>
```

Worked fine with me.

Comment: Id is a normal part of the html and javascript, so how you can say that, i dont know.

Comment: I tried this still gives null value for target

Comment: I tried that worked fine.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It was just a wild guess. As I thought its a default attribute so cant be used this way. Didn't work for me too. I tried with Id1 and it worked fine.

Comment: @TalhaAsif where did you put the javascript script in HTML?

Comment: @TH https://jsfiddle.net/talha_asif_77/v23jr1a4/4/

Comment: @TalhaAsif works fine here because it has one html file but I have two cotton.html and reports.html which both have <script src="{% static 'javascripts/allpredicted.js' %}"</script> , so I think queryselector selects button from reports.html

Comment: @TalhaAsif Problem is that OP's code is most likely getting executed before the html is rendered.